# Ignoring a value in tuple comparison but still retrieving it

Tags: python, set, tuples

I'm working with a set that contains tuples of the form `(position, name)` and need to check if a value already exists in the set for the name while ignoring the position.

Is there a way that I can use the `in` operator similar to `value in my_set`, ignoring the position variable in the tuple during comparison, but still retrieving it? Something similar to `(_, value) in my_set` or `(*, value) in my_set)`, but those don't work, first one returning an incorrect value, and the second raising a SyntaxError.

Obviously I can use a loop or a generator comprehension like `value in (tup[1] for tup in my_set)`, but that doesn't retrieve the position variable from that tuple, and I was curious if there was some form of one-liner comprehension that would do this.

Comment: `if val in [name for (position, name) in my_set]:`

Comment: @Sam That would work if I was just checking for the existence of val in the set, but I want to check if `val` exists anywhere within the set and then retrieve that value from the set. Not sure if I explained that clearly or not.

Comment: @PatrickArtner I'm working with a list view in a GUI, so I've got the data stored in a list and was toying around with using sets instead to stop duplication, and that raised this question. But the more I think about it, doing it with dictionaries might make more sense and just doing `contents.keys()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in O(n) with the existing data structure (iterating the set), but for O(1) you'll have to change data structure. You will need to make a lookup:

```
from collections import defaultdict

positions = defaultdict(list)
for position, name in my_set:
    positions[name].append(position)
```

Now this is an O(1) operation:

```
name in positions
```

Retrieving all per name:

```
for pos in positions[name]:
    ...
```

If you want this to  keep in synch with `my_set` mutations, then you will need to add in hooks for updating `positions` at the same time as adds/deletes to `my_set`.  It might be better to rethink the underlying data structure entirely, for example, using a dict instead of a set in the first place.

Comment: Since you're setting `default_factory` to `None` when you're done with it, maybe just use `setdefault` and a regular dict?  `positions = {}; ... positions.setdefault(name, []).append(position)`